# Display an attribute while grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to display all DR's column values while grouping using PT, PS, TPT, WT, TWR and MID at the same time.
For example, the first and last row should be grouped together since they have the same values and display in the DR column PTPS and PSWT.

```html
<Table>
<TR>
  <TD>PT</TD>
  <TD>PS</TD>
  <TD>TPT</TD>
  <TD>WT</TD>
  <TD>TWR</TD>
  <TD>MID</TD>
  <TD>DR</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD>20</TD>
  <TD>3</TD>
  <TD>181</TD>
  <TD>0</TD>
  <TD>104</TD>
  <TD>0</TD>
  <TD>PTPS</TD>
</TR>
  <TR>
  <TD>87</TD>
  <TD>1</TD>
  <TD>188</TD>
  <TD>8</TD>
  <TD>87</TD>
  <TD>0</TD>
  <TD>PSTPT</TD>
</TR>
  <TR>
  <TD>87</TD>
  <TD>1</TD>
  <TD>188</TD>
  <TD>40</TD>
  <TD>87</TD>
  <TD>1</TD>
  <TD>PSWT</TD>
</TR>
  <TR>
  <TD>20</TD>
  <TD>3</TD>
  <TD>181</TD>
  <TD>0</TD>
  <TD>104</TD>
  <TD>0</TD>
  <TD>PSWT</TD>
</TR>
  </Table>
```

Comment: Please provide your database structure (table and columns) from Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY PT,PS,TPT,WT,TWR,MID
```

Comment: This syntax dosen't work in Access. Could you please help me out

Comment: support your question with your database structure